# INVALID_REQUEST when sending a request with address_component

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm trying to get to grips with the Places API and I am getting an invalid request when I enter the `address_component` as a field. The `formatted_address` works though I understand that should not be used if we want to parse it programatically.

Sample request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?fields=address_components%2Cname%2Ctype&input=George%20Street&inputtype=textquery&key=MY_API_KEY

Response:

```
{
    "candidates": [],
    "error_message": "Error while parsing 'fields' parameter: Unsupported field name 'address_components'. ",
    "status": "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

Comment: Per [the documentation (at least for the Javascript Place Service)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult.address_components) address_components is only available from the `.getDetails` request, I would think that would be true of the web service as well.

Comment: Yeh you're right. It doesn't show it for the web documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place#Place